# How can I install npm packages without the source code

Tags: npm

Is it possible to install an npm package without all the other artifacts. For instance install only the content of the dist folder for the jQuery npm package?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but the NPM site seems to have good documentation on this. Have you already read through this? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Thanks kayleeFrye_onDeck, I did read through that, but could not find a way to just pull the 'binary' without the rest of things.

Comment: Why do you want the binaries only?

Comment: Less clutter, I get a lot of other stuff when all I need is the minified and non minified versions of the libraries and any dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It remains to the module publisher to exclude such files as sources, docs, tests ... and only include build and binary files when they publish their npm package (via `prepublish` hooks, `.npmignore` files, etc ...).

Not all maintainers are aware / take that in account ... The only thing you can do, as a module consumer (when you npm install) is to use the `--production` flag, not to install `devDependencies` (but that's not what you're looking for)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation